# Deafult Value not being set from reg file

Tags: registry

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[registry\data\key]
@="Test Value"
```

When I import the above value, if I include for example

```
"example"=dword:00000001
```

all the data is inserted correctly, but the (default) isn't set to what's in the reg file, it still just shows (value not set)

```
@="Test Value"
```

according to documentation should be able to set this, but it's not.

Comment: Do you have permission to set the value in question?

Comment: I merging the reg file while logged in as the local admin.

Comment: Which I checked has full permissions to this key.

Answer (score 8):

I was also having this problem (eg. dword:00000001 working and string (REG_SZ type) not).

Solved by using "\\" instead of "\" inside the string:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\Python.exe]
 @="C:\\Programming\\Python25\\Python.exe"
```